# What is the probability that the mean of N samples is lower than a limit when sample is normal distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, average, sampling

> The time it takes a person to complete the crossword puzzle in the newspaper is known to be normally distributed, with a mean of 35 minutes, and with a standard deviation of 6 minutes.
>
> Suppose that 9 people are selected at random, and each person completes a crossword puzzle. What is the probability that the **average** time to complete the puzzles is no more than 34 minutes?

Hi guys, I need some guidance in order to solve this problem.

My first step was to find the $\text P(x\le 34)$ that represents the probability that ONE person resolve the puzzle in less than 34 minutes.

I found it, it is equal to $0.4338$.

However, I have no idea what to do after this.

Comment: what are you defining $X$ by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0.4338$ is the probability that *one* person, selected at random, would take no more than $34$ minutes to complete the puzzle. You are interested in the probability that *nine* people, selected at random, would require a *mean time* of no more than $34$ minutes to complete the puzzle.

It seems that we should be considering the [sampling distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution) associated with a sample of nine from the given population for this problem.

Notice that even though the mean of the *population* is 35 minutes, the mean of *a random sample of nine people* depends on which nine people are in the sample.

Imagine we generate a new data set by repeatedly sampling nine people from the population and recording the mean of the sample each time.

It turns out that, by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), this new data set will have a normal distribution (for large samples, even if the original population is not normally distributed) with the same mean as the original population.

This new data set will further have a standard deviation $\sigma_{\bar x}$ (which we refer to as a [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) in the context of the original population) that is related to the standard deviation of the original population $\sigma$ and the sample size $n$ via:

$$\sigma_{\bar x}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$$

(This makes sense because we would expect a larger sample to have a mean more similar to the population mean than a smaller sample would, on average, and notice that this boils down to $\sigma_{\bar x}=\sigma$ for a sample size of $n=1$, as expected. It is a result worth exploring in more detail, however, with simulations, for example.)

In any case, you are now interested in $\text P(X\le34)$ given that $X\sim \text N\left(35,\frac{6^2}{9}\right)$, or the probability that the sample mean is no more than $34$ given that it is normally distributed with mean $35$ (same as original population mean) and standard deviation $\frac 6 3 = 2$ (smaller than the standard deviation of the original population), that is, $0.3085$.